# Provided hex string is not a valid Object ID

Tags: mongodb, go

Hi am coding a Go/MongoDB API where i am posting the body with the fields name, gender and age. This works well as i can see all the posts i've made in MongoDB console using  db.users.find().

I also get a console log`Created new user with ID: 6429e257a0a49409810d654e` which is great.

But I get "Error parsing ObjectID from request parameter: the provided hex string is not a valid ObjectID"  i try to get the user in postman using the url:
http://localhost:9000/user/6429e257a0a49409810d654e

The id 6429e257a0a49409810d654e is generated by `u.Id = primitive.NewObjectID()` in the CreateUser function.

But the error is generated at the start of the GetUser funciton when it tried to convert the id string to a ObjectId.
`oid, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(id)`

Any idea how i can fix this? as i'm using NewObjectID which is from the new mongodb driver for GO which should generate the right id.

## User Struct in my models

```
import "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"

type User struct {
    Id     primitive.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Name   string             `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Gender string             `json:"gender" bson:"gender"`
    Age    int                `json:"age" bson:"age"`
}
```

## The CreateUser and GetUser functions in my controllers

// The CreateUser method creates a new user in the database

```
func (uc *UserController) CreateUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    // Create a new User object and decode the JSON-encoded user data from the request body
    u := models.User{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&u)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Error decoding request body: %s", err.Error())
        return
    }

    // Create a context with a timeout of 5 seconds
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    // Generate a new MongoDB ObjectID for the user and set the user's ID field
    log.Println("Before generating ObjectID")
    u.Id = primitive.NewObjectID()
    log.Printf("Generated ObjectID: %s\n", u.Id.Hex())

    // Insert the user into the "users" collection in the "mongo-golang" database
    _, err1 := uc.client.Database("mongo-golang").Collection("users").InsertOne(ctx, u)
    if err1 != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Marshal the inserted user object into a JSON-encoded byte slice
    uj, err := json.Marshal(u)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Error marshaling user: %s", err.Error())
        return
    }

    // Set the response headers and write the JSON-encoded user object to the response body
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\n", uj)
}
```

## GetUser

```
func (uc *UserController) GetUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
    // Extract the ID parameter from the request parameters
    id := p.ByName("id")

    // Convert the ID string to a MongoDB ObjectID
    oid, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(id)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error parsing ObjectID from request parameter: %v", err)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }
    log.Printf("Converted ID parameter to ObjectID: %v\n", oid)

    // Create a context with a timeout of 5 seconds
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    // Retrieve a user with that ID from the "users" collection in the "mongo-golang" database
    u := models.User{}
    filter := bson.M{"_id": oid}
    err = uc.client.Database("mongo-golang").Collection("users").FindOne(ctx, filter).Decode(&u)
    if err != nil {
        if err == mongo.ErrNoDocuments {
            log.Printf("Error retrieving user: %v", err)
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
            return
        }
        log.Printf("Error retrieving user: %v", err)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Marshal the retrieved user object into a JSON-encoded byte slice
    uj, err := json.Marshal(u)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error encoding user as JSON: %v", err)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Set the response headers and write the JSON-encoded user object to the response body
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\n", uj)
}
```

Comment: Parsing `"6429e257a0a49409810d654e"` works just fine on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/CBdFW7LVM7C). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: nice, i did not know about go playground.. and strange it's able to parse it! i'll try make a reproducible example with my code on there and see what i get, thanks!

Comment: am i passing the id into the url in postman correctly? i.e ```http://localhost:9000/user/6429e257a0a49409810d654e``` ?